# How to change path to save output date ? it's only saving in form location

Tags: c#

i need to change outlook_file location to network share drive
can you advice any solution ?

it will only save in form location

```
const string PATH = "C:\\Temp\\Formularz\\";
        const string TASKS_FILE = "lista_zadan.txt";
        const string USERS_FILE = "lista_uzytkownikow.txt";
        const string OUTPUT_FILE = "dane.txt";

private void SaveToFile()
    {
        if (!File.Exists(PATH + OUTPUT_FILE))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(PATH + OUTPUT_FILE))
            {
                sw.Write("Data\t");
                sw.Write("Użytkownik\t");
             }
```

and if i change  OUTPUT_FILE location it doesnt work , it will save only if i leave OUTPUT location same as PATH

Comment: You didn't post any relevant code. Did you *try* using the correct path?

Comment: Please expand your question to showcase the actual code.

Comment: I added more code.

Comment: a change (PATH + OUTPUT.FILE)) to (@"c:\testLocation\" + OUTUPUT.FILE)) and it works
ticket can be closed.

Answer (score -1):

You would want to look at the [File.Move](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.file.move?view=netframework-4.8) Method i think it does exactly what you are trying todo.

Code would look something like this

```
string path = @"path_to_file";
string path2 = @"path_to_dest";

File.Move(path, path2)
```

If you want to change you log file output just change to path to the perfered File

Comment: The pointless approach of saving+moving (as opposed to just saving it in the right location) aside; the source of OP's issue (not using an absolute path) would be just as much of a problem with using `File.Move`.